# Dojo parse unparsed widjits

Tags: zend-framework, dojo

Zend framework adds the dojo.parser.parse(); to your script if you have widgets on the page, but not if you don't - makes sense. But I have a common js file which should set up lightbox images within all pages, and for this i need dojo.parser.parse(); to be included. I can add it to my common js file, but if I do, the parser runs twice and dojo breaks because all widgets in the page are getting added twice.

*How can I set my js up to effectively look for unparsed items, or even better, would be to detect if dojo.parser.parse(); has already been run?* (Unfortunately Zend doesn't assign the dojo.parser.parse(); to a variable)

Answer (score 1):

Once `dojo.parser.parse()` has finished the parsing of widgets, all the widgets references can be found at the global object `dijit.registry._hash`. You can use a simple test to check whether this object is empty to determine whether `dojo.parser.parse()` has been called.

This approach only works when you only create widgets declaratively.